# Roxygenize fails with... is.call(call) is not TRUE

Tags: r, roxygen2

Every time I try to `roxygenize` a package I get this error:

```
Error: is.call(call) is not TRUE
```

The results of a `traceback()`:

```
11: stop(sprintf(ngettext(length(r), "%s is not TRUE", "%s are not all TRUE"), 
        ch), call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
10: stopifnot(is.call(call))
9: standardise_call(call, env)
8: object_from_call(call, env, preref)
7: (function (call, ref, comment_ref) 
   {
       preref <- parse.preref(as.character(comment_ref))
       if (is.null(preref)) 
           return()
       preref$object <- object_from_call(call, env, preref)
       preref$srcref <- list(filename = file, lloc = as.vector(ref))
       add_defaults(preref)
   })(dots[[1L]][[1L]], dots[[2L]][[1L]], dots[[3L]][[1L]])
6: mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
5: Map(extract, parsed, refs, comment_refs)
4: FUN(c("/home/path/to/package/file1.r", 
   "/home/path/to/package/file2.r", 
   .... # list of files truncated 
   "/home/path/to/package/doc.file.r")[[25L]], 
       ...)
3: lapply(r_files(base_path), parse_file, env = env)
2: parse_package(base_path, load_code)
1: roxygenize("~/Current/r/path/to/package/")
```

Has anyone experienced this problem before? I'm not even sure how to debug it further.

Comment: Have you tried `options(error=recover)`, then browsing in levels 7+?  This is what I have done with this type of situation.  Hopefully variable contents will help.  Additionally, looks like error is in doc.credobb.r (is that really an r file?).

Comment: Thanks Brodie, that led me to it. I made a foolish error, instead of `NULL` at the end of my documentation block for the `?package` I had `NA`.

Comment: Please file a bug report on github.

Comment: https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues/194

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs if, instead of the typical `NULL` value that one puts at the end of the documentation for the package, one uses `NA`. Simply updating to `NULL` will remove the error.

Comment: Yep, this is true. However, this is quite annoying given that `NA` is specifically given as a hello-world example in the roxygen vignette. And yes, the vignette comes from roxygen, not roxygen2, but then, roxygen2 does not have a vignette or a howto or a tutorial or a FAQ. So much for literate programming.

Comment: Roxygen2 does have a how-to, it's just kind of hidden: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/ See the links under the heading "Documentation"

Comment: Cute. Thank you, this would have saved me a ton of time.